# How to implement libgdx touchDragged?

Tags: android, touch, libgdx

I'm stuck on implementing touchDragged listener using libgdx.

Here is my code and can anyone suggest how to drag image when user touches it and than moves finger?

I use stage and actor and I want to catch touchDragged event on actor.

Thanks.

```
public void create () {
    Texture.setEnforcePotImages(false);

    stage = new Stage();
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    // create a SpriteBatch with which to render the sprite
    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    // load the sprite's texture. note: usually you have more than
    // one sprite in a texture, see {@see TextureAtlas} and {@see TextureRegion}.
    texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("ball3.png"));
    Skin skin = new Skin();
    skin.add("default", new Label.LabelStyle(new BitmapFont(), Color.WHITE));
    skin.add("ball", texture);
    Image sourceImage = new Image(skin, "ball");
    sourceImage.setBounds(50, 125, 100, 100);
    stage.addActor(sourceImage);

    // create an {@link OrthographicCamera} which is used to transform
    // touch coordinates to world coordinates.
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();

    // we want the camera to setup a viewport with pixels as units, with the
    // y-axis pointing upwards. The origin will be in the lower left corner
    // of the screen.
    camera.setToOrtho(false);
}

public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    stage.draw();
    Table.drawDebug(stage);



    // if a finger is down, set the sprite's x/y coordinate.
    if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
        // the unproject method takes a Vector3 in window coordinates (origin in
        // upper left corner, y-axis pointing down) and transforms it to world
        // coordinates.
        camera.unproject(spritePosition.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps:

1. You need to check if the finger is touching the object that you want to move. Here are some useful methods to get your finger's position:

   ```
   Gdx.input.getX();
   Gdx.input.getY();
   ```
2. You need to use a variable to track whether the finger is moving, when touching.
3. If the variable is **true**, you change the object's position to your finger's position.
4. You disable your variable when the finger is no longer touching the screen.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use InputProcessor:

```
public class MyInputProcessor implements InputProcessor{
    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode){
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode){
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button){
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button){
        return false;
    }
    @Override 
    public boolean keyTyped(char character){
           return false;
    }
    @Override 
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer){
        return false;
    }
    @Override 
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY){
        return false;
    }
    @Override 
            public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
                    return false;
            }   
}
```

Make it a Field:

```
MyInputProcessor inputProcessor;
```

And in onCreate():

```
inputProcessor = new MyInputProcessor();
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputProcessor);
```

That way you can just implement your code in the touchDragged callback.